# GUI con arreglo

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar una ventana, ingresar unos valores y que se vean reflejados en un panel, cree el arreglo, pero me imprime los valores que no he puesto en null, necesito hacer dos ciclos anidados, pero estoy atorado y ya no sé como hacerlo. Les paso el código, ojalá me puedan ayudar.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Ventana v;
    JLabel lnombre, ldireccion, lcorreo;
    JTextField tfnombre, tfdireccion, tfcorreo;
    JButton botona, botonc, botons;
    JTextArea area;
    JPanel panel;
    String Datos[][];
    String mensaje = "";
    int P = 0;

    public Ventana() {

        lnombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
        lnombre.setBounds(15, 20, 450, 20);

        ldireccion = new JLabel("Direccion");
        ldireccion.setBounds(15, 50, 450, 20);

        lcorreo = new JLabel("Correo");
        lcorreo.setBounds(15, 80, 450, 20);

        tfnombre = new JTextField();
        tfnombre.setBounds(100, 20, 450, 20);

        tfdireccion = new JTextField();
        tfdireccion.setBounds(100, 50, 450, 20);

        tfcorreo = new JTextField();
        tfcorreo.setBounds(100, 80, 450, 20);

        botona = new JButton("Aceptar");
        botona.setBounds(60, 300, 140, 20);
        botona.addActionListener(this);

        botonc = new JButton("Cancelar");
        botonc.setBounds(220, 300, 140, 20);
        botonc.addActionListener(this);

        botons = new JButton("Salir");
        botons.setBounds(380, 300, 140, 20);
        botons.addActionListener(this);

        area = new JTextArea();
        area.setBounds(10, 120, 565, 150);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        panel.add(lnombre);
        panel.add(ldireccion);
        panel.add(lcorreo);
        panel.add(tfnombre);
        panel.add(tfdireccion);
        panel.add(tfcorreo);
        panel.add(botona);
        panel.add(botonc);
        panel.add(botons);
        panel.add(area);

        add(panel);
        setSize(600, 380);
        setTitle("Unidad 1");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        Datos = new String[5][3];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ventana v = new Ventana();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == botona) {
            Capturar();
            P = P + 1;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == botonc) {
            Borrar();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == botons) {
            Salir();
        }
    }

    void Capturar() {
        Guardar();
        Mostrar(Datos);
        // area.setText("Los datos ingresados son: \n Nombre : " + tfnombre.getText() + "\n 
        //Direccion : " + tfdireccion.getText() + "\n 
        //Correo : " + tfcorreo.getText());
    }

    void Borrar() {
        area.setText("");
    }

    void Salir() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    void Guardar() {
        if (P < 5) {
            Datos[P][0] = tfnombre.getText();
            Datos[P][1] = tfdireccion.getText();
            Datos[P][2] = tfcorreo.getText();
        } else {
            mensaje = "Memoria llena.";
        }
        tfnombre.setText("");
        tfdireccion.setText("");
        tfcorreo.setText("");
    }

    void Mostrar(String[][] a) {


       // if(a[i][j] != "" || a[i][j] !=null);
        area.setText("Nombre: " + a[0][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[0][1] + "     Correo: " + a[0][2] + "\n"
                + "Nombre: " + a[1][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[1][1] + "     Correo: " + a[1][2] + "\n"
                + "Nombre: " + a[2][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[2][1] + "     Correo: " + a[2][2] + "\n"
                + "Nombre: " + a[3][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[3][1] + "     Correo: " + a[3][2] + "\n"
                + "Nombre: " + a[4][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[4][1] + "     Correo: " + a[4][2] + "\n" + mensaje);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He intentado modificar al mínimo el código, no se si es la idea que tienes en mente:

```
 void Guardar() {
    if (P < 5
            && !estaVacio(tfnombre.getText())) {
        Datos[P][0] = tfnombre.getText();
        Datos[P][1] = tfdireccion.getText();
        Datos[P][2] = tfcorreo.getText();
        P = P
                + 1;
    } else {
        mensaje = "Memoria llena.";
    }
    tfnombre.setText("");
    tfdireccion.setText("");
    tfcorreo.setText("");
}


void Mostrar(final String[][] a) {
    area.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        if (!estaVacio(a[i][0])) {
            area.setText(area.getText()
                    + "Nombre: " + a[i][0] + "     Direccion: " + a[i][1] + "     Correo: " + a[i][2] + "\n");
        }
    }

}

private boolean estaVacio(final String nombre) {

    return nombre == null
            || nombre.isEmpty();

}
```

He puesto el aumento de P = P + 1 dentro de Guardar y lo he borrado del actionPerformed, así no aumenta si no se ha introducido el nombre. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Si me posicionara en una linea del arreglo de la linea 2 o 3 y la quisiera borrar (dando por hecho que existiera el boton borrar), que metodo deberia inplementar para borrar ese arreglo?

Comment: El problema para borrar, es que una vez creado un arreglo no se puede redimensionar. Como mucho podrías dejar los valores en blanco o copiarlos en otro arreglo con el método Arrays.copyOfRange. Otra forma si lo que quieres es borrar y añadir dinámicamente, es utilizar los objetos ArrayList o LinkedHashMap.